# Fetching value from file and incrementing it by one in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
//using namespace cout;
int main(){
    cout << "\n";
    int i = 1; 
    
    while(i > 0){
        cout << "Input Data" << endl;
        string   firstName , userName , password;
        char character;
        ofstream userWriteFile("tableData.txt" , ios::app);
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> firstName;
        cout << "User-Name: ";
        cin >> userName;
        cout << "Password: ";
        cin >> password;
        
        userWriteFile << "\n";
        int n = 0;
        n =  i + 0;
        userWriteFile << n << " " ;
        userWriteFile << firstName << "\t\t";
        userWriteFile << userName << "\t\t";
        userWriteFile << password << "\t\t";
        
        userWriteFile.close();
        
        cout << "Do You Want more Entries or Not (Press the Key Y(Yes) / N(No)): ";
        cin >> character;
        if(character == 'y' || character == 'Y'){
            i++;
        }
        else if(character == 'n' || character == 'N'){
        //otherWise print the table 
        ifstream userReadFile("tableData.txt");
                               
                while ( 1 ){
                userReadFile >> n >> firstName >> userName >> password;     
                if(userReadFile.eof())  
                    break;              
                    cout << "\n";     
                    cout << n << "." << " " << firstName << "  " << userName << "  " << password << "  " << "\n";
                }
                
                break;
                userReadFile.close();
        }
        else{
            cout << "invalid Character";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is the part of the code in which it reads the data in the text file and make it appear on complier window after taking data.

i have tried printing it in the tabular form and for sure i achieved it as well. But know the problem is that when i recompile the code the record that i add again start from count 1 not from the count where i previously left it.

How can i get the previous data of the list that i add in the first time that i complied and run the code. and then increment each and every record on the basis of the previous value of the code.

i.e,

1. sam   samcodeonline  12234
2. adam   adam@fdsa    23212

suppose in the first compilation i have added two records

and as i make the second compilation it would not start from 3 it would again start from 1

i.e,

1. leo   leo@fdas    12345

Comment: if you guys want more code i can even provide it to you because as a newbie i am stuck on this problem for 3 days now.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: FYI, this code has some of the same problems as [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/364696). All the code from `while (1) {` through `if (userReadFile.eof()) break;` should be replaced with the single line: `while (userReadFile >> n >> firstName >> userName >> password) {` to handle I/O errors aside from EOF (with a side-benefit of less verbose code).

Comment: Have tried to minimize it, more minimization is not making sense at all.

Comment: Why do you show `leo` as the output? Is the input file changing?

Comment: Given the way you have written your code, the number associated with `leo` is whatever number was next to it in the input file.

Comment: let me explain the code data in the compiler as well as in the text file appears like this      1. sam samcodeonline 12234
2. adam adam@fdsa 23212                                                                                                              1. leo  leo@fdas 12345                                                                                                                         i want the leo to get the 3 value as i rerun the compiler to add the data again                           3. leo  leo@fdas 12345

Comment: now where to store the last count and then to fetch it , after which we would increment the existing list by one.

Comment: One idea is to read ALL the records into a vector. Add any new records you need to the vector. Delete any records you don't want from the vector. Sort the vector to get the order you want. Before your program ends, WRITE the vector out to the file. The next time you run your program, it will reload the vector that you have written.

Comment: so by the use of vector can i update and delete the record in the code as well @tbxfreeware

Comment: Yes. Your mistake is not writing the file at the end of your program. That's why the file goes back to the the way it was before.

Comment: ***Have tried to minimize it, more minimization is not making sense at all.*** I think the complaint is you minimized it too far that its no longer a complete example. The goal of your minimal complete example is we paste it in our IDE and it compiles and runs your code and gives us the same result with no other changes on our part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that you are not writing the file back to the disk after making changes.

One approach is to read ALL the records into a vector. Update the vector as needed, and, before your program ends, write the vector back out to the file.

For this to work, you will need to use a `struct` to hold user data.

```cpp
struct User
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string user_name;
    std::string password;
};
```

A `struct` is like a new data type. You can declare a variable of type `User` like this:

```cpp
User u;  // `u` is a variable
```

Use the *dot operator* to access the *fields* of a struct:

```cpp
u.first_name = "leo";
u.user_name = "leo@fdas";
u.passward = "12345";
```

Declare a vector of structs like this:

```cpp
std::vector<User> users;
```

You can treat a vector like an array. For example, you can use square bracket to access the elements of a vector.

`push_back` is one of the important vector functions. It adds a new *element* to the end of a vector. In the case of our vector of Users, it add another user.

```cpp
// Starting with the empty vector declared above.
users.push_back(u);                // add user leo to the vector
std::cout << users[0].first_name;  // dislplay "leo" (using the dot operator with `user[0]`)
```

You can learn more about vectors from your textbook.

##### A complete program

Here is a complete program for updating the file. Note the record numbers (1., 2., 3., etc.) are not stored in the file. Rather, they are calculated in function `display_users`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct User
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string user_name;
    std::string password;
};

void display_users(std::vector<User> const& users)
{
    int n{};
    for (auto const& u : users)
    {
        std::cout
            << ++n << ". " << u.first_name
            << "\n  user name : " << u.user_name
            << "\n  password  : " << u.password
            << "\n\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string file_name{ "tableData.txt" };

    // Open file for input.
    std::ifstream ist{ file_name };
    if (!ist.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open input file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Read file into vector.
    User u;
    std::vector<User> users;
    while (ist >> u.first_name >> u.user_name >> u.password)
        users.push_back(u);
    ist.close();

    std::cout << "AFTER READING FILE\n\n";
    display_users(users);

    // Add a user.
    std::cout 
        << "ADD A USER\n\n"
        << "Enter first name: ";
    std::cin >> u.first_name;

    std::cout << "Enter user name: ";
    std::cin >> u.user_name;

    std::cout << "Enter password: ";
    std::cin >> u.password;
    std::cout << "\n\n\n";

    users.push_back(u);

    std::cout << "AFTER ADDING A USER\n\n";
    display_users(users);

    // Open file for output.
    std::ofstream ost{ file_name };
    if (!ost.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open output file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 2;
    }

    // Write file.
    for (auto const& u : users)
        ost << u.first_name << " " << u.user_name << " " << u.password << '\n';
    ost.close();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Output

Here is the ouput from a sample run.

```
AFTER READING FILE

1. sam
  user name : samcodeonline
  password  : 12234

2. adam
  user name : adam@fdsa
  password  : 23212



ADD A USER

Enter first name: leo
Enter user name: leo@fdas
Enter password: 12345



AFTER ADDING A USER

1. sam
  user name : samcodeonline
  password  : 12234

2. adam
  user name : adam@fdsa
  password  : 23212

3. leo
  user name : leo@fdas
  password  : 12345
```

##### Response to new code posted in OP

Now that the OP has posted his complete program, I understand his question better. He wants to read the file to see what number was posted along with the last record, and use that number to continue when new records are written.

The easiest way to do that is to open and read the file completely, just to learn what number belongs to the last record. That is what the following program does.

I have added many comments giving tips on the things I changed from the program in the OP.

Hope this helps.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string file_name = "tableData.txt";

    // If you write a record number for each user (along with his 
    // other data), then you must read the entire file to discover 
    // the record number of the last record.
    // 
    // That is what this first loop does.

    // Open the file for input.
    std::ifstream userReadFile{ file_name };
    if (!userReadFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open input file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Read all the records. Only the data from the final record 
    // is saved.
    // 
    // This is the proper way to test for input failure.
    // The `eof` test used in your program is not recommended.
    // See the comments posted by other users.
    //
    // If any one of `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` cannot be read,
    // then `userReadFile` will be placed into a failed state, 
    // and `userReadFile.fail()` will be `true`.
    // 
    // This is a shortcut way to test `userReadFile.fail()`.
    // When used as the condition for an if-statement or 
    // while-loop, the expression `userReadFile >> x` will 
    // attempt to input `x`, and then return `!userReadFile.fail()`
    // to the if-statement or while-loop. Note the 
    // exclamation point operator `!`. This is the same 
    // as "while not fail" or "if not fail."

    int lastRecordNumber = 0;  // anticipating an empty file
    int a;
    std::string b, c, d;
    while (userReadFile >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
        lastRecordNumber = a;
    }
    userReadFile.close();

    // At this point, `lastRecordNumber` holds the number
    // of the last record that was read successfully.
    // This is the answer to your original question.
    // 
    // Next, run a loop to input records from the user.
    // It is convenient to open the file for output only 
    // once, and hold it open during this loop. We will 
    // close the file when this loop is finished.

    // Open file for output.
    std::ofstream userWriteFile(file_name, std::ios::app);
    if (!userWriteFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open output file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 2;
    }

    std::string firstName, userName, password;
    bool inputMore = true;
    while (inputMore)
    {
        // Input record from user.
        std::cout << "Input Data" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: ";
        std::cin >> firstName;
        std::cout << "User-Name: ";
        std::cin >> userName;
        std::cout << "Password: ";
        std::cin >> password;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        // Write record to file.
        // Note that `lastRecordNumber` is incremented before 
        // writing it to the file.
        //
        // Output exactly one line, followed a by newline.
        // Do not output any other newlines.
        // Note that the tab character has fallen out of favor.
        // You can use `std::setw` to get better control of 
        // alignment. For now, however, the tab remains.

        userWriteFile
            << ++lastRecordNumber
            << ' ' << firstName
            << '\t' << userName
            << '\t' << password
            << '\n';

        // Ask user whether to input more records.
        // Keep the Yes/No code together. Run a small loop
        // to trap invalid entries.
        for (;;)
        {
            std::cout << "Do You Want more Entries or Not (Press the Key Y(Yes) / N(No)): ";
            char character;
            std::cin >> character;
            std::cout << '\n';
            if (character == 'y' || character == 'Y') {
                inputMore = true;
                break;  // break out of the for-loop
            }
            else if (character == 'n' || character == 'N') {
                inputMore = false;
                break;  // break out of the for-loop
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Invalid Character\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

    // Now we close the output file.
    userWriteFile.close();

    // All that remains is to read and display the file.
    // Note that this loop should not be placed inside 
    // the loop the writes to the file.

    // Open the file for input.
    userReadFile.open(file_name);
    if (!userReadFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open input file: " << file_name << "\n\n";
        return 3;
    }

    while (userReadFile >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
        std::cout << a << ". " << b << "  " << c << "  " << d << "\n\n";
    }
    userReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Sample Output

```
Input Data
Name: leo
User-Name: leo@fdas
Password: 12345

Do You Want more Entries or Not (Press the Key Y(Yes) / N(No)): n

1. sam  samcodeonline  12234

2. adam  adam@fdsa  23212

3. leo  leo@fdas  12345
```

Comment: i have made the whole code to appear now, i want the user to add as much data as he/she wants and then when he clicks on the n button the data would be printed in the tabular form. and as i would rerun the compiler the code should start from the , value other than the previous value and should be its increment.  you can even run the code that i have provided

Comment: your solution has also helped alot. but it is a complex one to understand as i am a new to this language.  @tbxfreeware

Comment: how in this code can i update and delete the saved record using the cpp code. basically it would form a CRUD operation using cpp. @tbxfreeware

Comment: this solution has solved the problem i was searching for , as i am having a low reputation of stackoverflow so , i can't upvote but my feedback is saved.

Comment: No problem. It's nice to know I helped. You may still be able to click the check mark ✔ to accept the answer. But, either way, thanks for the comment.

Comment: could you help me with the edit and delete record, part of it as well. @tbxfreeware

Comment: Unfortunately, I had a flare up of carpal tunnel syndrome, today. My arm hurts, and I can only type with only one hand. Sorry to say, that means I won't be typing any long answers for a few days.